# Windows 7 crash when install on SSD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, ssd, crash

I'm trying to install Windows 7 on an SSD drive but the system crashes after the first restart during install. I've tried different SATA ports and a different brand of SSD drive but still get the same result.

To try and get around the problem, I tried installing on a hard drive then used Ghost to clone the hard drive to the SSD. That worked but when Windows boots on the SSD it crashes a couple seconds after startup. However, if I boot into safe mode, it doesn't crash.

I have AHCI enabled in the bios.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

When Windows crashes, the screen goes black and the system immediately stops (fans stop spinning, etc). The is no BSOD and no error message. Based on the fact that everything works fine when using a hard disk and the system doesn't crash when using an SSD in safe mode, I'm guessing that it's a driver issue related to SSDs. The problem is figuring out which driver is causing the problem.

Comment: which crash? Do you get a BSOD? if yes, which STOP code do you see? Post more details!